# Which word would be most suitable? Shipping cost, shipping price, or shipping fee?

Tags: word-choice

Please help me decide.
I have an Online Store and provide worldwide shipping.
Which word should I use in the part that we charge customers for the shipping?
Shipping cost? Shipping price? or Shipping fee?

I kind of would like to make customers feel the most comfortable?
Or do you suggest any other words?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Shipping costs" is probably the most common term in the US.  The others would be interpreted as ambiguous -- do they include both you packing charges and the fee charged by the carrier?

Comment: @HotLicks I charge only the estimated carrier's shipping price.

Answer (score 1):

Of the words you offer - price, cost, fee - the most widely used in this context is probably *cost*. The goods you sell have a "price" included in which is your profit. I imagine you do not want your customers to think you are also profiting on the shipping, so best avoid that word. "Fee" implies the same.

Many online stores do not use any of these words and simply call it "shipping", eg:

> Price £40
>   + £3.00 shipping

Also, in British English, the term "postage and packing" was once widely used, but "shipping" seems to have taken over for online stores.

Comment: Thank you. "Cost", I guessed so, but was not positively sure.
I use just "Shipping" for points that I can use, but there are some parts that I cannot use just it, for example, FAQs and T&C.